# Equivalence between the category of bimodules and the functor category

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, abelian-categories

Let $S$ and $R$ be rings,  $\mathcal{C}=(S,R)$-bimod where morphisms are bimodule homomorphisms, $\mathcal{D}=$Func$(R$-mod, $S$-mod$)$ where morphisms are natural transformations. I'm trying to show that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent.

Obviously, each object $X\in\mathcal{C}$ gives rise to an object in $\mathcal{D}$: the functor $X\otimes_R (-):R$-mod$\to S$-mod. In other words, we have a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ given by $F(X)=X\otimes_R (-)$.

But how do you define the inverse functor $G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$? How do you go from a functor $H:R$-mod $\to S$-mod to a $(S,R)$-bimodule? I feel like this is somehow related to the hom-tensor adjunction, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It's not true. The true statement is the Eilenberg–Watts theorem.

Comment: The equivalence becomes true if one restricts to **cocontinuous** functors.